# What is easy way to create two equal bundles(first - es6, second - es5) in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to create two different bundles via Webpack. These bundles have same entry point. I use TypeScript and as result i need two files:

**app.js** with ES6 syntax
**app.legacy.js** with ES5

Is it possible to create with Webpack's loaders only?

I can to resolved it with Webpack + Gulp. Webpack(with ts-loader) creates bundle app.js(ES6) and Gulp watcher creates app.legacy.js (via Babel). But I would like a more elegant solution with only Webpack.

Comment: Could you try defining multiple configurations (return an array, webpack will pick it up) covering both cases? I have a feeling generating **app.js** could be tricky to pull off, though.